# How to delegate interface implementation to other class in C#

Tags: c#, interface

Assume the following class:

```
public class MyEnum: IEnumerator
{
    private List<SomeObject> _myList = new List<SomeObject>();
...
}
```

It is necessary to implement the IEnumerator methods in MyEnum. 
But is it possible to 'delegate' or redirect the implementation for IEnumerator directly to _myList without needing to implement the IEnumerator methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Method 1:**
Continue to use encapsulation and forward calls to the List implementation.

```
class SomeObject
{
}

class MyEnum : IEnumerable<SomeObject>
{
    private List<SomeObject> _myList = new List<SomeObject>();

    public void Add(SomeObject o)
    {
        _myList.Add(o);
    }

    public IEnumerator<SomeObject> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _myList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyEnum a = new MyEnum();
        a.Add(new SomeObject());

        foreach (SomeObject o in a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o.GetType().ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**
Inherit from List implementation you get that behavior for free.

```
class SomeObject
{
}

class MyEnum : List<SomeObject>
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyEnum a = new MyEnum();
        a.Add(new SomeObject());

        foreach (SomeObject o in a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o.GetType().ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Method 1** allows for better sandboxing as there is no method that will be called in List without MyEnum knowledge. For least effort **Method 2** is preferred.

Comment: It'd sure be nice to have some syntactic sugar shorthand notation for method 1, e.g. something like `private readonly IEnumerable<SomeObject> _myList implements IEnumerable<SomeObject>;` (borrowed from Delphi's syntax for this). Does anybody know if anything like this has ever been considered and if so, why it hasn't been added to C# yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
public class MyEnum : IEnumerator {
    private List<SomeObject> _myList = new List<SomeObject>();
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return this._myList.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

The reason is simple. Your class can contains several fields which are collections, so compiler/enviroment can't know which field should be used for implementing "IEnumerator".

**EIDT:** I agree with @pb - you should implements IEnumerator<SomeObject> interface.

Comment: The interface to implement is IEnumerable not IEnumerator.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using pb's method, this isn't possible for a “simple” reason: the interface method needs to get passed a `this` pointer as the first argument. When you call `GetEnumerator` on your object, this pointer will be your object. However, in order for the invocation to work on the nested list, the pointer would have to be a reference to that list, not your class.

Therefore you explicitly have to delegate the method to the other object.

(And by the way, the advice in the other reply was right: use `IEnumerator<T>`, *not* `IEnumerable`!)

Answer (score 0):

If you want return a collection in a way where the caller is unable to modify the collection, you might want to wrap the List into a ReadOnlyCollection<> and return IEnumerable<> of the ReadOnlyCollection<>.

This way you can be sure your collection will not be changed.

Answer (score -1):

Not unless you derive from List<T>.

```
public class MyEnum : List<SomeObject>, IEnumerable<SomeObject>{}
```

Comment: Ok, this will work but I want to be sure that the calling code is incapable of type-casting the enumerator to List again and add or remove objects from it.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for your input and explanations. 
Eventually I have combined some of your answers to the following:

```
    class MyEnum : IEnumerable<SomeObject>
{
    private List<SomeObject> _myList = new List<SomeObject>();
    public IEnumerator<SomeObject> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Create a read-only copy of the list.
        ReadOnlyCollection<CustomDevice> items = new ReadOnlyCollection<CustomDevice>(_myList);
        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

This solution is to ensure the calling code is incapable of modifying the list and each enumerator is independant of the others in every way (e.g. with sorting).
Thanks again.

Comment: You can pass by the `ReadOnlyCollection` because `IEnumerable`s are immutable anyway! The user'd have to upcast and guess the original type of the list in order to modify it. Copying the list is IMHO not a very good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Note that thanks to [duck-typing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2007/07/18/duck-notation/), you can use `foreach` on any object that has a `GetEnumerator` method - the object type need not actually implement `IEnumerable`.

So if you do this:

```
class SomeObject
{
}

 class MyEnum
 {
    private List<SomeObject> _myList = new List<SomeObject>();

    public IEnumerator<SomeObject> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _myList.GetEnumerator();
    }
 }
```

Then this works just fine:

```
MyEnum objects = new MyEnum();
// ... add some objects
foreach (SomeObject obj in objects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I realize this isn't a general answer to the original question, but it is relevant to the specific use case provided in the question.

Comment: If you realize that you're not answering the question then *don't post an answer to the question*.  Answers are for answering the question, not for posting random trivial facts that you find interesting.  This isn't actually helping you in this situation; there's no reason for you to not actually implement the interface in this situation.

Comment: The question was how to delegate the implementation of an interface in order to avoid writing boilerplate code. My response is a potential answer for the common case of delegating the implementation of IEnumerable, which also happens to be the example used by the OP. I debated whether to make it a comment or an answer, and decided to make it an answer. It *is* an answer to a specific form of the question.

Comment: And yet you spent the entirety of the answer talking about how there's no need to actually implement the interface, something that's not necessary or even helpful or desirable in this circumstance.  You're just explaining an off topic, not helpful, tangent, rather than actually answering the question.  That makes it not an answer (and not even a useful comment).

Comment: Please re-read the body of the original question: _"is it possible to 'delegate' or redirect the implementation for IEnumerator directly to _myList without needing to implement the IEnumerator methods?"_ - my answer addresses this pretty directly.

Comment: The question asks how to easily implement the interface.  It doesn't ask how to use the object in a `foreach` without implementing `IEnumerable`.

Comment: The OP is a little fuzzy on what they want (`IEnumerator` vs. `IEnumerable`), and seems mainly interested in avoiding boilerplate code, which my answer addresses. /shrug/

Comment: So since you weren't sure if the OP wasn't an `IEnumerator` or an `IEnumerable` you choose to provide neither?  (For the record though, the question is *very* clear about asking for an `IEnumerator` implementation, reader simply pointed out that having an `IEnumerable` is probably the correct option in this situation.)